# C++ Проверка условий в шаблонах и зачем нужно *= при использовании type traits

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

Всем привет! Я видел некоторый код с type traits, где вместо

```
template <typename T, typename enable_if_t<..something>>
```

Делают примерно так:

```
template <typename T, typename enable_if_t<..something>*=nullptr>
```

Или так:

```
template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<..something>>
```

Чем отличаются все эти 3 записи?(надеюсь я в них не ошибся)
И второй вопрос: как лучше всего делать проверки на различные условия(для типов) в шаблонах?

Comment: Нынче лучше делать проверки с использованием концептов...

Comment: `* =` - это два отдельных символа. `*` - указатель, `=` - стоит перед аргументом по умолчанию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два популярных способа:

- `typename = std::enable_if_t<??>`
- `std::enable_if_t<??, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr`

Второй способ лучше, по двум причинам:

1. Нельзя отключить проверку, передав какой-то свой тип в этот шаблонный аргумент.
2. Можно сделать несколько функций, которые будут отличаться только условием. Если сделать это с первым способом, то компилятор будет ругаться на переопределение функции.

У второго способа есть разные вариации: `std::enable_if_t<??, int> = 0`, `std::enable_if_t<??> * = nullptr` (что эквивалентно `std::enable_if_t<??, void *> = nullptr`), и т. п. Но они плохи тем, что позволяют сгенерировать несколько разных копий шаблона, передав туда разные шаблонные аргументы. А у `std::nullptr_t` возможное значение только одно, поэтому с ним так не сделать. (В С++20 для этих целей также подходит какой-нибудь пустой класс.)

Comment: В С++20 можно привести к типу `std::nullptr_t` какой-нибудь пустой класс?

Comment: @maestro Нет, в смысле `std::enable_if_t<??, MyClass> = MyClass{}`.